# " Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Invalid document reference. Document references must have an even number of segments,but Users has 1." Reactjs

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to get the data from firebase version9.8 in react.js project, but I am getting the error:

> Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Invalid document reference. Document references must have an even number of segments, but Users has 1.

how can I resolve this?

( I want to get the write the data in firebase on submit button so so i write the code in onSubmitHandler )

```
const onSubmitHandler = async (event) => {  
    console.log(event);
    console.log("saving data to database request is Trigered...")
    // Hear we push the data in firestore databae

    await setDoc(doc(db, "Users",), {

      name:collectionOfStates},{merge: true}


      
    ).then(() => console.log("Data Save in firebase")).catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    })

  }
```

Comment: what is ```setDoc```, what is ```doc```? We can't help you if you don't show us more code

Answer (score 1):

Your code tries to write data into the `Users` collection, instead of in a document under it, which is not possible.

If you want to write to a specific, known document, specify its document ID in the call to `doc`:

```
                      // 
setDoc(doc(db, "Users", "idOfDoc"), {
  name:collectionOfStates},{merge: true}    
)
```

If you want to add a new document to the collection with an auto-generated ID, use `addDoc` instead of `setDoc`:

```
// 
addDoc(doc(db, "Users"), {
  name:collectionOfStates},{merge: true}    
)
```